# Pass coordinates parameters to geoserver pgrouting service from Leaflet wms tile layer

Tags: geoserver, wms, leaflet, layers, pgrouting

I've configurated a pgRouting service in Geoserver, [following the steps on the documentation](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/geoserver.html) it's easy to accomplish.

Reading the documentation, existing examples, etc.. I've come to undestand how the call must be made from the Javascript code:

```
        var myLayer = L.tileLayer.wms("http://192.168.0.34:8080/geoserver/pgroutingtest/wms", {
            layers: 'pgroutingtest:pgroutingtest',
            format: 'image/png',
            transparent: true,
            version: '1.0.0',
            tiled:true
        });
        map.addLayer(myLayer);
```

The call is ok, no errors returned, but also no image added to the map.

My doubt is, how can I pass the origin and destination coordinates(x1,y1,x2,y2) as parameters to the pgrouting service in order to calculate the route?

In the [example that the pgRouting documentation](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/ol3_client.html#select-start-and-destination) give us, this is done as follow:

```
var viewparams = [
  'x1:' + startCoord[0], 'y1:' + startCoord[1],
  'x2:' + destCoord[0], 'y2:' + destCoord[1]
];
params.viewparams = viewparams.join(';');
result = new ol.layer.Image({
  source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost:8082/geoserver/pgrouting/wms',
    params: params
  })
});
map.addLayer(result);
```

But this example, is made with OpenLayers 3. **How can achieve this with Leaflet?**

Answer (score 2):

Just try to pass the viewparams as part of the WMS_URL:

```
  var viewparams = [
      'x1:' + startCoord[0], 'y1:' + startCoord[1],
      'x2:' + destCoord[0], 'y2:' + destCoord[1]
    ];

    var baseURL="http://192.168.0.34:8080/geoserver/wms";

    var better_BaseURL=encodeURI(baseURL+"?viewparams="+viewparams.join(';'));

var myLayer = L.tileLayer.wms(better_BaseURL, {
            layers: 'pgroutingtest:pgroutingtest',
            format: 'image/png',
            transparent: true,
            version: '1.0.0',
            tiled:true
        });
        map.addLayer(myLayer);
```

[image]